# How can i Put My Project Between Try and catch in laravel

Tags: laravel, error-handling

Hello Guys Please I Have A Big Project And I Want To Put All Project Classes Between Try And Catch To Handle Errors Because If I Put All Classes Between Try & catch manually It Takes A Lot of time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to put try catches on the functions in order to know and handle the error, if you put a try catch IN THEORY on your whole project, then your project will fail anyway since there is no clear way of catching and handling your error